# What question(s) does category theory help answer?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

I have been studying category theory for the past couple of months and I'm struggling to understand *what's the point?*

I'm going to build up an intuition from what I know to understand if I am on the right path.

- Historically, Category Theory was created to answer some question(s) in the field of Topology - which deals with questions about properties preserved under deformations (to keep it simple). Hence, it's understandable to have *function composability* be a *first class citizen* in category theory. That is, it's intuitive (for me) to appreciate the reasoning behind the creation of category theory and why composability matters from a non-mathematical perspective.
- Assuming one understands the various constructs like functors, natural transformations etc., *what* does on *do* when viewing/modeling the problem from a category-theory POV?
- Let's say I correctly identified and created a category $C$ in my domain (which may be outside of mathematics). What's my next step? Is the idea to find a connection with another category $D$ that one may uncover - (either within my domain or outside)? By *connection* I mean the ability to *transform* $C \rightarrow D$. The "question" I then answer is the *insight* of this transformationary *connection* between possibly disparate concepts, which is illuminating by itself.
- Let's say I don't have (or find) a category $D$. Then what? Does one *play around* with category $C$ to see where things lead and thus develop further insight about it? The *act of playing* will surely involve *transformationary thinking* from above AFAIK.

Given the above my understanding seems to be this:

> Category theory offers a framework for mathematical reasoning via the
>   lens of *transformations*  to prove (or disprove) whatever that we set
>   out to do. Instead of "deductive logic" that one sees in elementary
>   geometry (or most of math IMO) you use *transformationary reasoning*
>   to allow you to go from $a$ to $b$. Thus, it's an alternative
>   framework in which to do mathematical reasoning, however, at a higher
>   level *between* other mathematical constructs vs. proving one of
>   Euclid's theorems (say).

*This* is my source of confusion - I have no idea if I'm right or wrong and even thinking about it the right way or *wildly off*. All books/resources introduce category theory "bottom up" i.e., laying out all the concepts, terminologies, definitions and providing information on how to use the framework, *for what exactly* is completely lost IMHO.

What are some questions I can see answered via category theory, preferably in a *step-by-step* fashion to help appreciate the *insight* to be gained from this POV and how it's *different* (or perhaps better) than what we have? Bonus points if the *question to be answered* is laid out at the start and *then* we transform the problem into a categorical language and do some reasoning there and transform the *insight* back into the language of the problem domain. *That* would be wonderful!

I've read books by Spivak and I only see him apply constructions but haven't found anything that does what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think the main benefit of category theory is the connections it forms between otherwise distinct branches of mathematics. It gives you an idea as to what common constructs appear in math. It's just another layer of abstraction which allows you to focus on what features of a category give it the properties it has.

Comment: @DonThousand - I genuinely understand and appreciate that part. However, seeing Category Theory constructs showing up in functional programming (for example) seems to imply that it's possible to "use this thinking" outside of finding similarities in math. I'm trying to hone in on what it means to "think" categorically and "how" to use the framework to solve the problems that you can phrase in that language

Comment: IMO, this question is misguided in its expectation that one can expect to give a unified answer to this sort of thing. Category theory solves a host of problems and answers a lot of different questions, and there's no reason to think there's an single theme that will link them all together. I could give you an overview of something in my field where category theory provided an insight, but it will either not be step-by-step, or it will be too technical for a non-specialist.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine - the goal is to find “an” example to allow learning by example. Downloading definitions and rules doesn’t necessarily imply one can use it. Perhaps if you could simplify your problem to isolate/explain what the problem was and how Cat helped that could be a good start IMO.

Comment: It's much harder to explain to a non-expert why category theory is useful than to just explain some category theory. Most people who know category theory well are in areas of pure math that are inconceivable without category theory, so that asking how category theory helps is a bit like asking how equations help with high school algebra--there are certainly answers, but not pat ones. If you want to know how category theory is good for functional programming, then you should ask *that*. For most other application areas, it's still an open question just how helpful category theory is.

Comment: @KevinArlin - I'm not asking "why it is useful". I'm _assuming_ it _is_. I'm seeking to understand its usefulness by _seeing it in action_ in some meaningful way. The question is my current best attempt at articulating what I would like to understand. As for functional programming - I think FP borrows a lot of _constructs_ from category theory (functor, monads etc.,) but doesn't _apply_ category _thinking_ in the design/reasoning of programs AFAIK (or if it does I'm yet to see a valid example other than _borrowing constructs_ - perhaps in designing type systems but I don't know enough to say).

Comment: I was going to mention the work of Olivia Caramello in the realm between Higher-Order Inuitionistic Logic and Topos Theory where she exploits categorical constructions to "unify" mathematical theories, but I then realised that to understand any of these concepts one needs to be proficient not only in categorical constructions that go far beyond functors and natural transformations, but also in those ideas borrwed from Mathematical Logic. In general, I think that seeing CT "in action" requires deep understanding not only of CT, but also the area of Mathematics to which you apply this thinking.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Having said this, I'm wondering if the implementation of categorical notions for New Foundations has been fruitful so far, but I'm not sure if there is someone in MSE with the required expertise to answer this.... What do you think Alice, sounds like a good question to you? ;-)

Comment: @Rick - Mysterious! But yes, it has helped put a finer point on some questions. For instance, a number of our current questions about the structure of NF's universe have gone from "what the heck?" to more specific questions about small definable subfibrations with certain embedding properties. :P

Answer (score 2):

This is by no mean a satisfactory answer to your question as I am not an expert. I am just going write how I feel about category theory.

According to my understanding, category theory has not designed to answer questions in any particular subject, but to model the abstract mathematics itself. It give us a bird-eye view of all mathematical theories and show us previously unseen/uncleared connections between different mathematical theories. Sometimes it reveals hidden structures that we haven't seen before and simplify existing theories. For example: Groups, Lie groups, algebraic group, Abelian groups, simplicial group, $2$-groups, Hopf algebras, etc are group objects in different categories. This understanding doesn't help us to prove particular properties of each structure, but captures all these different notions into a single definition. This inspire us to think about previously unexplored group (and cogroup) objects in nice categories like group objects in category of Simple Graphs.

Moreover, category theory can think of as the theory of transporting data between different mathematical disciplines. For example homology, homotopy, linear representations of groups and many more and functors, and same is true for natural transformations (I am pretty sure that you have heard the story of origin of category theory). This is a nice platform to understand duality theorems (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)) and [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/duality)) and generalized spaces. Two of the well known duality results are the Stone duality, and Gelfand duality. Both ultimately led mathematicians to discover new generalizations for topological spaces called locales and noncommutative spaces. Affine schemes is a generalization of algebraic varieties and,  smooth loci is a generalization of smooth manifolds both obtain via dualities. In fact, mathematicians are still exploring nice duality results between analytic spaces and algebraic spaces. Another interesting direction in the generalization theme is (co)completing categories by freely adding limits and colimits, which is called yoneda completion.

Beside above mentioned applications, category theory itself has few deep theorems [like](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629362/what-are-some-examples-of-hard-theorems-in-category-theory) the general adjoint functor theorem, Yoneda lemma, Brown's representability theorem. And consequences of these theorems uncover deep results in all over mathematics.